# Using scrollbars with canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to put together a window that displays a bunch of labels generated from a dict. I'm having trouble getting the scrollbars to work properly. They won't stick to the sides of the frame when I resize the window, and I can't get the canvas to respond to the scroll command. I need the window to support a large number of labels.

```
from Tkinter import *
from math import floor

bits = {}

#the dict is then built

class Bitbox(Canvas):
def __init__(self, parent, bitdict, *args, **kwargs):
    Canvas.__init__(self, parent, background="black")
    self.bitdict = bitdict
    self.parent = parent
    self.lbllist = []

    n=0
    for i in bitdict.keys():
        label = Label(self, text=i, bg='black', fg='green')
        n += 1
        label.grid(row = ((n-1)%30), column=int(floor((n-1)/30)))
        self.lbllist.append(label)


def main():

    root = Tk()
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.grid(sticky=N+S+E+W)
    bts = Bitbox(frame, bits)
    bts.grid(row=0, column=0)
    vbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL)
    vbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
    vbar.config(command=bts.yview)
    hbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    hbar.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)
    bts.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set)
    hbar.config(command=bts.xview)
    bts.config(yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
    bts.config(scrollregion=(0,0,500,1000))

    root.mainloop()
```

Clearly I'm new at all this. It's entirely possible I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how these widgets interact. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

to get the scrollbar to react to the mouse bind the mouse to the scrollbar like this:

```
def on_mousewheel(event):
    bts.yview_scroll(-1*(event.delta/120), "units")


def main():
    global bts

    #your code...

    root.bind_all("<MouseWheel>",on_mousewheel)
```